# Do javax.persistence.transient and java.bean.transient do the same thing?

Tags: java, hibernate

Does the `javax.persistence.transient` annotation and the `java.beans.transient` annotation do the same thing? I know that the latter was only introduced in Java 7. I'm just curious as we recently upgraded to Java 7 on our servers and I'm wondering if Hibernate will work the same with either of the annotations.

Comment: The first one is JPA annotation and can use Hibernate-JPA implementation. Its major purpose is to exclude when the entity object is about to map and persist to the columns in database table. Though not sure on second annotation's usage, it indicate not to serialize and similar to `transient` keyword.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Wundwin Born said before:

javax.persistence.transient will make sure that Hibernate will ignore that particular field from saving it into the db and vice-versa.

java.beans.transient will make sure that the particular field will be ignored by the encoders (derived from Encoder). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Transient.html