# Why is Hibernate attempting to map a @Transient method?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an annotated entity POJO that I am trying to use with Hibernate.

The class has a number of business logic methods with names like `getX`. I have annotated these with the `@Transient` annotation, example source below:

```
import java.beans.Transient;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class TestEntity {

    private String id;

    @Id
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Transient
    public Collection<String> getAllGames()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, Hibernate still appears to be attempting to map these methods. The following error is output when initialising Hibernate:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:
>   java.util.Collection, at table: TestEntity, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(allGames)]  at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:455)   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:422)   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597)
>     at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:451)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
>   ...

Hibernate is configured using `<mapping class="...">` entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">
          org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
          org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
       </property>

       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
          jdbc:derby:db
       </property>

       <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
       <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
       <property name="show_sql">true</property>

       <mapping class="TestEntity"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am running with Hibernate 5.2.10.Final.

**Why is Hibernate attempting to map this transient method?**

Comment: What else does this question need to be reopened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Transient` annotations are of the wrong package:

```
import java.beans.Transient;
```

They should be from the `javax.persistence` package:

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;
```

See also: [Do javax.persistence.transient and java.bean.transient do the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056397/do-javax-persistence-transient-and-java-bean-transient-do-the-same-thing)